# Tailwindcss & Angular only updating styles when I run ng serve, but not when it's detecting changes. How can I make it so it rechecks on every change?

Tags: angular, tailwind-css

So I have an angular project with tailwind, every time I use a new class I have to rerun ng serve so that it rebuilds the styles with the classes. Is there any way to make it recheck?

tailwind config:

```
module.exports = {
    darkMode: 'media', // or 'media' or 'class'
    mode: 'jit',
    theme: {
        extend: {},
    },
    content: [
        "./src/**/*.{html,ts}",
    ],
    variants: {
        extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [],
}
```

Edit: I'm using Angular's and tailwind's latests versions

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^13.3.9"` in your `package.json` file. After that you have to run this command `npm install`
I think it will fix your problem. Its work for me.